# JSON parsing using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following valid JSON

```
[
    {
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Comp",
                "data": [
                    753,
                    384,
                    864,
                    654
                ],
                "color": "#FFAC3F"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ind",
                "data": [
                    642,
                    456,
                    983,
                    564
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Store",
                "data": [
                    832,
                    243,
                    646,
                    777
                ],
                "color": "#FF0000"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to return all the data inside "series" but doing something like say assigning this to a variable and then using data.series is not returning anything.  How would I do this using jquery or javascript?  This data is actually getting returned in a jquery JSON ajax request like so....

```
$.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
```

Comment: If you're calling `$.getJSON()`, you don't have to parse it at all. The parsed object is passed to your callback function ready-to-use.

Comment: i thought so too but when i do alert(data.series) it is not alerting anything except [Object]

Comment: Right - see the answers to your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is wrapped in an array. You want

```
data[0].series
```

---

For a better visual, review this

```
var data = [{foo: "bar"}, {hello: "world"}];
```

To get `foo`, you would use

```
data[0].foo; // "bar"
```

To get `hello`, you would use

```
data[1].hello; // "world"
```

---

Considering you have

```
var data = [{series: [...]}];
```

You need to use

```
data[0].series; // [...]
```

Comment: Got it thanks, painful though, to do something like data[0].series[1].name what if I wanted all the series data like [
            {
                "name": "Comp",
                "data": [
                    753,
                    384,
                    864,
                    654
                ],
                "color": "#FFAC3F"
            }, is there some tostring function or something?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data[0].series)
});
```